# Finding combinations from a set of options?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations

Say I have this scenario:

- 240 shirts
- 340 pairs of shoes
- 90 pairs of pants
- 300 jackets
- 50 watches

How can I find out the amount of combinations I can make out of these items? Would I just multiply all of the numbers together?

Answer (score 1):

Bingo!
Yes use the Multiplication rule to get the number of combinations.